# Обратиться к функции другого класса

Tags: java, android

Простите, как я могу обратиться к методу getName из активности NavigationActivity?

```
public class UserProfile {

private String name, email;
private int sex, avatar;

public UserProfile(String name, String email, int sex, int avatar){
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.avatar = avatar;
}

public void setName(String name) { // изменяет имя пользователя (логин)
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

В авторизации (LoginActivity) идет создание этого профиля (то есть использую UserProfile(и здесь данные)). А в другом классе мне нужно эти данные как-то получить. А как это сделать?

Comment: почитайте про Singleton

Comment: передайте через intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе UserProfile (для примера) добавил еще методы "сеттер" и "геттер"
для работы с полем email

```
public class UserProfile {

private String name, email;
private int sex, avatar;

public UserProfile(String name, String email, int sex, int avatar){
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.avatar = avatar;
}

public void setName(String name) { // изменяет имя пользователя (логин)
    this.name = name;
}

public void setEmail(String email) { // изменяет почту пользователя
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
```

}

"Другой" класс, в котором для использования данных из класса типа UserProfile
создаем объект этого класса и сразу заполняем данными, как того требует его конструктор. Затем через методы "геттеры" класса UserProfile 
получаем данные полей name и email

```
public class OtherClass{
//создаем объект класса UserProfile
UserProfile up = new UserProfile("vasya", "vasya@email", 1, 888);

// через методы "геттеры" получаем данные полей name и male
private String nameUser = up.getName();
private String mailUser = up.getEmail();

// создаем методы для использования данных из UserProfile
public void printName(){
    System.out.println(nameUser);
}

public void printEmail(){
    System.out.println(mailUser);
}
```

}

Основной класс MainClass, где объект типа OtherClass через свои
методы получает данные из UserProfile (в д.сл. выводит их на консоль)

```
public class MainClass{

public static void main(String[] args){

    //в основном классе создаем объект типа OtherClass
    OtherClass oc = new OtherClass();
    //через его методы используем данные полей 
    //класса UserProfile
    oc.printName();
    oc.printEmail(); 
}
```

}

Вывод программы:

vasya

vasya@email

Answer (score 0):

```
String name = x.getName();
```

где х - название объекта класса UserProfile